# how To get date greater then or equal to today from day name (Sunday,Monday,etc) in mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql

if today date is 14-07-2016 and day name is Thursday

if day name in column of table is monday then query should return date is 18-07-2016 (Beacuase Todaye is Thursday.)

if day name in column of table is
Day is Tuesday then date is 19-07-2016 ,
if
Day is Wednessday then date is 20-07-2016
if 
Day is Thursday then date is 14-07-2016
if
Day is Friday then date is 15-07-2016
if
Day is Saturday then date is 16-07-2016
if 
Day is Sunday then date is 17-07-2016

I have Used This Query

```
SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),WEEK(NOW(),1), weekday), '%X%V %W') as edate, From table_event
```

In this Query 
it work fine but it return past date and i don't need past date i need only future dates

so please guide me for it ASAP.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL . The SP or function should calculate the next date for friday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984704/sql-the-sp-or-function-should-calculate-the-next-date-for-friday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have Tryed More Times And Then i Got Finally My Answer as

SELECT * , IF( (
STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR( NOW( ) ) , WEEK( NOW( ) , 1 ) , weekday ) ,  '%X%V %W' ) >= CURDATE( ) ) , STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR( NOW( ) ) , WEEK( NOW( ) , 1 ) , weekday ) ,  '%X%V %W' ) , (
DATE_ADD( STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR( NOW( ) ) , WEEK( NOW( ) , 1 ) , weekday ) ,  '%X%V %W' ) , INTERVAL 7 
DAY )
)
) AS edate
FROM tbl_event

the output of this query is And please note today date is 14-07-2016.
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPdP7.png)

This code work fine, it is tested code.
Thanks.