# SQL Server - get next Friday in DATETIME

Tags: sql-server

To get the last Friday of any date the query follows:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1-(DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) % 7),GETDATE())
```

How can I get the **next friday?**

Comment: add 7 days......................?

Comment: @MitchWheat If `GETDATE()` happens to fall on `11:59:59` of a Friday, _and_ a leap second also happens to occur, then obviously your suggestion would fail.

Comment: leap seconds? pffft!  Where does OP say they are concerned with leap seconds?

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(d,6-(DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) % 7),cast(GETDATE() as date))

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Hey. Wait a second....

Comment: IMO it would be better to ask why the algorithm does what it does, vs asking how to manipulate it.  It's easy to Google the official Microsoft documentation for DATEADD, and DATEPART.  The last GETDATE() may be tricky but it's the number of days since Jan 1 1900 (which was a Monday).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5984859/3854195) to a similar question which takes `@@DATEFIRST` into consideration:

**EDIT/CORRECTION**:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 13 - (@@DATEFIRST + (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) %7)), GETDATE())
```

Comment: If today is Saturday (and @@DATEFIRST is 7), the function returns the previous Friday, not the next Friday.

Comment: @RazvanSocol - I've updated the answer with the correct placement of the parentheses. Thanks.